# sed, capture only the number

Tags: bash, sed, numbers

I have this text file:

```
some text A=10 some text
some more text A more text
some other text A=30 other text
```

I'm trying to use sed to capture only the numeric value of A. Using this

```
cat textfile | sed -r 's/.*A=(\S+).*/\1/'
```

I get:

```
10
some more text A more text
30
```

But what i really need is:

```
10
0
30
```

If the string `A=` does not exist output a `0`. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: You should accept the most satisfying answer.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot think on a one-liner, so this is my approach:

```
while read line
do
grep -Po '(?<=A=)\d+' <<< "$line" || echo "0"
done < file
```

I am using the look-behind `grep` to get any number after `A=`. In case there is none, the `||` (else) will print a `0`.

Answer (score 1):

I love code-golf!

```
sed -e 's/^/A=0 /; s/.*\<A=\(\d\+\).*/\1/'
```

This prepends `A=0` to the line before substituting.

Comment: Ah, I like your solution better. Is the `\<` thing making sure you get the last 'A='? What does it actually do?

Comment: Informally, `\<` matches the beginning of a word

Comment: @cluracan, We always get the last `A=` because `.*` is greedy. That's why we prepend `A=0` instead of appending.

Comment: Oh, cool. I'm always too paranoid to use such fluid rules - but they work!

Answer (score 1):

try this one-liner:

```
awk -F'A=' 'NF==1{print "0";next}{sub(/ .*/,"",$2);print $2}' file
```

with your data:

```
kent$  echo "some text A=10 some text
some more text A more text
some other text A=30 other text"|awk -F'A=' 'NF==1{print "0";next}{sub(/.*/,"",$2);print $2}'
10
0
30
```

Answer (score 1):

[gawk](/questions/tagged/gawk)

```
awk '{$0=gensub(/^.*A=?([[:digit:]]+).*$/, "\\1", "g"); print($0+0)}' file.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/.*A=\([0-9][0-9]*\).*/s//\1/;t;s/.*/0/' file
```

Look for the string `A=` followed by one or more numbers and if it occurs replace the whole line by the back reference. Otherwise replace the whole of the line by `0`.

Comment: +1 this is the only one that is 100% sed, is accurate enough and actually works (and also quite short). b.t.w. what does the ;t; between the two replacements ? (oh, btw, you even can scrap one of the [0-9] from the pattern)  :-)

Comment: @thom `t` checks to see if the last substitute command (if any) was a success and if so bails out. As there is no goto place name following the `t` command it ends the processing of the line. If the substitution was not a success (or no substitute has been done) it replaces the whole line with a `0`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to do two different commands - the first replaces lines without 'A=' with the line 'A=0', the second does what you did.

So

```
cat textfile | sed -r 's/^([^A]|A[^=)*$/A=0/' | sed -r 's/.*A=(\S+).*/\1/'
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
sed -r -e 's/.*A=(\S+).*/\1/' -e 's/.*A.*/0/'
```

Answer (score 0):

Some grep-sed-cut combination:

```
grep -o 'A=\?[0-9]*' input | sed 's/A$/A=0/' | cut -d= -f2
```

Produces:

```
10
0
30
```